# Dúvida sobre a responsabilidade de um get()

Tags: javascript, c#, java, java-ee, getters

É aceitável ter um método *getter* que recebe um parâmetro para poder ter uma variação de retorno? Exemplo:

```
getAllNome("M"); <- retorna tudo que for masculino.
getAllNome("F"); <- retorna tudo que for feminino.
getAllNome(); <- retorna todos os nome, não importa o sexo.
```

A responsabilidade do *getter* é retornar valores, portanto, usar parâmetros para ele pode causar confusão?

---

**Observação:** Muitos lugares onde estudei sobre *getters* e *setters* dizem que não deve receber argumento. Por que não? Não é mais simples um *getter* que recebe argumentos para ter retornos diferentes? Quando digo "aceitavel" é se estou cometendo um erro. Ou fugindo de algum padrão que não conheço?

[GET E SET](http://www.tiexpert.net/programacao/java/get-set.php)

> **Get**
>
> Nomeamos um método acessor com get toda vez que este método for
>   verificar algum campo ou atributo de uma classe.
>
> Como este método irá verificar um valor, ele sempre terá um retorno
>   como String, int, float, etc. Mas não terá nenhum argumento.

Comment: A pergunta é muito interessante. A resposta seria bem ampla. C#, por exemplo, não permite argumento em propriedade, mas isso porque a linguagem é melhor construída que Java, que permite porque o `get()` no geral é um método qualquer de uma classe. Portanto, correto não é. Se algumas linguagens permitem, o problema é da construção dessas linguagens.

Comment: Indepedente da linguagem, acho que se deve perguntar: minha classe tem necessidade de fornecer esses acessores? É um bom design para minha classe que eles sejam fornecidos? As respostas para isso vão depender da situação.

Comment: Relacionado: [Getters e Setters são obrigatórios ou facilitadores?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33728/3117)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não sei se isso pode ser considerado subjetivo ou não, mas há evidências que o número de bugs em um programa é proporcional à quantidade de linhas de código nesse programa. Independentemente de linguagem. Linguagens/bibliotecas mais expressivos (i.e. que fazem muito com pouco código) tendem a produzir códigos mais curtos, e portanto com menor número de bugs.

E o que isso tem a ver com a pergunta? Simples: se passar parâmetros opcionais servir pra tornar seu código mais conciso, então faça! Não se preocupe demais com a "pureza" do código: boas práticas são boas não porque "alguém disse que são", mas porque resolvem/evitam uma série de problemas. Mas se você não enxerga problema nenhum numa abordagem, não há por que evitá-la.

Eu não gosto de *getters* e *setters*. Eu não gosto de atributos privados. Mas dependendo do tipo de projeto e equipe, eles podem ser coisas necessárias (ex.: equipes numerosas compostas de programadores inexperientes, que têm mais chance de cometer erros). Nesse caso, mais importante do que seguir o padrão X ou Y, é importante seguir um padrão **consistente**.

Por exemplo, o jQuery tem várias funções que funcionam como propriedades: `html`, `text`, `attr`, `prop`, `css`, `data`... Todas elas funcionam da mesma maneira: sem argumentos, são um *getter*; com um argumento, são um *setter* (argumentos adicionais podem existir, no início). O nome é curto, não precisa ficar escrevendo o prefixo (`getText` vs. `setText`)... E o mais importante: a mesma convenção é utilizada em toda a biblioteca, então sem surpresas!

Em Java, há uma convenção bem rígida sobre os nomes dos métodos e o que eles devem fazer. Fugir dessa convenção é problemático, pois obriga quem não está familiarizado com seu código a aprender/decorar uma convenção nova. Entretanto, `getAllNome` não segue - que eu saiba - nenhuma convenção pré-estabelecida, de modo que você pode adotar a sua. E mesmo se seguisse, é preciso pesar os prós e os contras, como discutido anteriormente.

Por fim, considere transferir essa responsabilidade para outra classe, de modo a tornar seu uso mais consistente. Java infelizmente não tem funções de primeira classe (nem *extension methods*), então é necessário fazer isso atrvés de uma classe auxiliar. Por exemplo, se sua função retorna um `List`, crie a interface/classe:

```
interface ListaFiltravel<T> extends List<T> {
    public ListaFiltravel<T> filtrar(String variacao);
    public ListaFiltravel<T> filtrar(String variacao, boolean inPlace);
}

class ArrayListFiltravel<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements ListaFiltravel<T> {
    public ListaFiltravel<T> filtrar(String variacao) {
        return filtrar(variacao, false);
    }

    public ListaFiltravel<T> filtrar(String variacao, boolean inPlace) {
        // Código para filtrar
        // Retorne a própria lista filtrada (inPlace == true) ou uma outra lista
    }
}
```

E chame seu método da seguinte forma:

```
meuObjeto.getAllNome().filtrar("M")
```

Desse modo, as responsabilidades ficam bem separadas. (Mas de novo: fazer isso produz códigos mais curtos? Se isso for algo que você só tem que fazer uma única vez, eu continuo a favor de deixar a pureza de lado e colocar a funcionalidade no próprio *getter*. Mas se puder ser reaproveitado em várias partes do seu sistema, então essa abordagem é melhor.)

Answer (score 9):

Na minha opinião há uma confusão acerca do conceito de getters e setters como sendo métodos acessores, cujo objetivo é garantir o encapsulamento protegendo os atributos de uma classe, e o exemplo de método proposto `getAllNome("M");` que embora possua prefixo `get` não tem a responsabilidade única de expor uma propriedade, fugindo assim da definição do que são os métodos acessores, como seria, por exemplo, o caso de um método `getNome()`.

Se desejamos recuperar o atributo `nome` de um conjunto de um tipo, digamos `Pessoa`, como é o caso do `getAllNome("M");` esse método não deveria participar da classe `Pessoa`, mas de uma outra classe com essa responsabilidade, que por sua vez só acessaria os nomes pelo get, *ou método acessor*, `getNome()` conforme exposto pelo @mgibsonbr. Ainda assim se for necessário que o método participe da classe, ele não poderia ser considerado um método acessor.

Por fim, embora sua necessidade possa ser discutida, quando estamos falando de métodos acessores, um `get` nunca receberá argumentos e um `set` receberá um, e somente um, argumento, do mesmo tipo que é retornado pelo getter.

Answer (score 5):

Falando em orientação a objetos, existem motivos para usar getters e setters.

Digamos uma classe Produto que contenha a propriedade preço. Esse preço sofre um desconto e sempre que obtermos esse valor, queremos que tenha aplicado o desconto. Neste caso, a propriedade privada garante que o preço não será obtido diretamente sem o desconto e implementamos no get redução do valor.

No seu caso, imagino que esteja tratando de uma classe pessoa. Uma pessoa (individual) somente tem um sexo. Por tanto o get irá retornar esse valor individual.(char)

No seu caso sugerido, o get funciona como uma query personalizada. Seria um método de objeto que contém várias pessoas e irá retornar uma array de objetos Pessoa que atendam os parâmetros da sua consulta. 
Existem padrões de projeto para implementar esse tipo de lógica. 
O padrão de projeto Repository prevê exatamente esse tipo de consulta personalizada: você implementa um getAllPessoas(), que retorna uma array de todos os obejtos Pessoa, um getAllSexo(char sexo), que retornaram uma array de objetos Pessoa com esse sexo. Aí então, de cada um desses objetos Pessoa você poderia chamar a função getNome() ou outra para obter dados de cada um.

Aconselho estudar [Design Patterns](http://robsoncastilho.com.br/2011/06/25/conhecendo-design-patterns-e-o-padrao-strategy/), o livro [Padrões de Projetos: Soluções Reutilizáveis](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=U91CYCqTCgkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=padr%C3%B5es%20de%20projeto&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hjs2U7OfK4XH0QGUkIAo&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=padr%C3%B5es%20de%20projeto&f=false), e [Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices in C#](http://robsoncastilho.com.br/2012/10/21/livro-agile-principles-patterns-and-practices-in-c/). São os padrões clássicos, mas existem muitos outros, como o Repository, que não está nesse livros. Os padrões ajudam muito a entender a aplicação de Orientação a Objeto.