# Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento, getters-setters

É comum que se ensine que o certo é deixar os atributos da classe privados e criar `getters` e `setters` para eles, tudo por causa do encapsulamento.

Isso não é a mesma coisa que deixar tudo público, já que você pode alterar e obter o valor livremente? Isso não cria apenas uma ilusão de encapsulamento? É recomendado ou não o seu uso? Por quê?

Comment: Em teoria, um *setter* devem não apenas setar o valor de uma variável, mas também tratar ao menos de forma básica o valor de entrada bem como validá-lo. Também, através de um *setter* você tem, dependendo da linguagem, tipagem.

Comment: Relacionado: [Dúvida sobre a responsabilidade de um get()](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10965/3117)

Comment: É apenas um "espírito", uma boa prática de programação dado o próprio paradigma. Seria complicado se todos pudessem mexer nos meus membros/órgãos deliberadamente. Entãos os getter's e setter's vêm afirmar essa ideia de que devemos "pedir" para definir ou aceder a algo que pertence a nós(objectos).

Comment: Vale a pena a leitura: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html

Comment: @Cold, isso é uma "péssima prática" você quis dizer? Getter e Setter sem propósito algum apenas complica o código, na prática nunca vi um deles que trate qualquer coisa em entidades ou em VOs, ninguém é doido de colocar lógica ali dentro, em domínios anêmicos, as regras ficam na camada de "Serviço". Só os uso quando sou "forçado" por algum "framework" que possui más práticas.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Concordo com todas as respostas. *Getters* e *setters* são essenciais.

Mas a questão é: eles são ***sempre*** necessários?

## O que realmente precisa ser acessado?

Ocorre que é prática comum criar-se *getters* e *setters* para todas as propriedades de uma classe. Não se reflete sobre a real necessidade nem sobre possíveis efeitos colaterais disso.

Muitos métodos são criados desnecessariamente, pensando talvez em que podem ser necessárias algum dia, mas nunca são usados. Isso só deixa o código mais propenso a erros.

## E a interface?

Embora *setters* e *getters* sejam um tipo de encapsulamento do atributo, a assinatura do método público faz parte de sua interface, sendo um tipo de "contrato" com as demais classes.

O atributo pode estar encapsulado, mas de forma alguma você está livre para mudar as implementações, já que qualquer mudança em atributo provavelmente irá afetar também a assinatura de algum método.

## E os objetos complexos?

Por exemplo, se minha classe tem uma lista:

```java
public class Turma {
    private List<Aluno> alunos; 
}
```

O que fazer? Colocar um `setAlunos`?

```java
public class Turma {
    private List<Aluno> alunos; 
    public void setAlunos(List<Aluno> alunos) {
        this.alunos = alunos;
    }
}
```

Ou gerenciar a lista internamente?

```java
public class Turma {
    private List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>(); 
    public void addAluno(Aluno aluno) {
        alunos.add(aluno);
    }
}
```

Existem várias situações onde é melhor não ter o método *setter*.

No primeiro exemplo, a lista fica "exposta". É possível que a implementação da lista passada por outro desenvolvedor não tenha algum método usado internamente implementado. Por exemplo, se a nossa classe adiciona alunos em algum momento, mas a lista passada é imutável.

## Objetos Imutáveis

Em cenários onde um objeto de negócio é compartilhado entre várias *threads* concorrentemente, *setters* podem causar efeitos indesejados. Objetos imutáveis (sem *setters*) são muito mais seguros e eficientes nesse sentido, pois não podem acabar num estado inconsistente devido à concorrência.

Além disso, se um objeto é passado a várias rotinas e serviços, os *setters* podem ser inadvertidamente chamados por alguma rotina deixando o objeto num estado inconsistente. Suponha que você já aplicou todas as regras de validação, mas antes de gravar os dados do banco de dados uma das rotinas chama um *set*. Aí você precisa "caçar" quem foi o responsável pela alteração.

Mais um ponto, é que alguns objetos poderiam se beneficiar de *cache* de informação. Por exemplo, se um dos atributos é calculado a partir de vários outros. Mas os diversos *setters* deixam essa implementação bem mais complexa.

Criar um objeto imutável não é difícil. Uma forma é permitir a definição de valores através do construtor e não ter métodos *set*. Exemplo:

```java
public class Turma {
    private List<Aluno> alunos; 
    public Turma(List<Aluno> alunos) throws ListaDeProblemasException {
        this.alunos = alunos;
        //valida e processa alunos como bem quiser
        //sabe-se que não irá mudar depois
    }

    public List<Aluno> getAlunos() {
        return alunos;
    }
}
```

## Validação no setter?

Usar *setters* para validação é interessante, até certo ponto.

Isso realmente pode se tornar um problema em casos onde um atributo depende de outro. Imagine, por exemplo, que você tem um método `setCPF` e outro método `setCNPJ`. Ambos só podem ser chamados, respectivamente, se o tipo da pessoa for `F` ou `J`. E se alguém resolver chamar aqueles antes destes?

Além disso, fica muito mais difícil o tratamento desse tipo de erro para, por exemplo, exibir a lista de erros para o usuário na tela.

## Conclusão

*Getters* e *setters* *podem* ser, sim, uma ilusão de encapsulamento em muitos casos, principalmente porque os métodos públicos de uma classe aumentam o acoplamento e o "compromisso" em manter todos aqueles métodos.

Não é que seja uma ilusão por si só, mas ela ocorre na cabeça dos programadores que acham que `encapsulamento = getter + setter`. Eles descobrirão mais tarde comportamentos "estranhos" no programa porque na verdade não há nada "escondido".

Uma implementação com o mínimo de método públicos deixa o código mais "seguro" e flexível.

Comment: Você tem razão sobre setters não serem sempre necessários. E eu gostei da dica sobre os objetos imutáveis, mas a questão de seu uso é que por princípio de projeto os atributos de um objeto assim não precisarão ser alterados após a sua criação. Se esse não for o caso, o uso de setters ainda garante o encapsulamento. Também não vejo tanta distinção no *acoplamento* entre ter um setter (mesmo que simples) e um atributo diretamente público. A dependência da propriedade vai ser praticamente a mesma. continua...

Comment: ... Então eu só discorto sobre eles serem uma ilusão. Mesmo no exemplo dos alunos (objeto complexo), a primeira opção é praticamente equivalente a deixar a lista pública, e assim simplesmente não se tem encapsulamento algum.

Comment: @LuizVieira Realmente. Não é que eu ache que é uma ilusão por si só, mas ela ocorre na cabeça dos programadores que acham que `encapsulamento = getter + setter`. Então eles descobrem mais tarde comportamentos "estranhos" no programa porque na verdade não há nada "escondido".

Comment: Entendi, então o ponto fundamental da sua resposta é que deixar público desnecessariamente é bobagem (seja de uma forma ou de outra), pois o encapsulamento começa em manter escondido o que não precisa/deve ser alterado. Fantástico, mas que tal trocar a sua conclusão atual por esse seu último comentário? Pessoalmente eu acho que fica muito melhor. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Boa sugestão. Feito.

Answer (score 31):

Usar um setter *não é uma ilusão de encapsulamento* porque a ideia é que a própria classe tenha todo o controle sobre a alteração de suas propriedades.

Se uma propriedade for naturalmente pública, esse controle é simplesmente inexistente e ai sim não existe encapsulamento algum. Qualquer fonte externa pode, a qualquer momento, alterar a propriedade com qualquer valor do tipo apropriado, e levar o objeto a um estado inadequado (considerando o que foi planejado pelo projetista).

Tendo um método setter para isso, o objeto pode - diante de uma tentativa de atualização - fazer validações necessárias, atualizar outras propriedades dependentes, etc, e assim garantir que o estado esteja sempre correto de acordo com o projetado.

Comment: Esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25997/7210) dá um exemplo do que aqui foi explicado.

Comment: Melhor resposta, +1! Entendi só de ler a primeira parte.

Comment: Pensei em um calculo de porcentagem como exemplo:      `public void SetPorcentagem(var qtade)
    {
        this.porcentagem = (qtade * valor) * 0,01;
    }`

Comment: @Marconi Obrigado. :) Sobre o exemplo, ele é bem bom, mas tem um detalhe: se a ideia é encapsular a porcentagem, o método deveria se chamar `SetQuantidade` (pois aí o cálculo e uso interno da porcentagem estará encapsulado até mesmo semântica e conceitualmente).

Answer (score 18):

A vantagem de se utilizar getters e setters é a possibilidade de se validar ou modificar dados quando se utiliza esse pattern.

Por exemplo, suponha que você tenha uma classe `Produto` com o atributo `preco` que recebe valores. Claramente, um valor negativo seria inválido. Logo, o `setPreco(int preco)` poderia se comportar da seguinte maneira:

```java
public void setPreco(int preco) {
    if (preco < 0) {
        this.preco = 0;
    } else {
        this.preco = preco;
    }
}
```

ou ainda:

```java
public void setPreco(int preco) {
    if (preco < 0) {
        // exceção do tipo runtime
        throw new NumberFormatException("Preco deve ser maior do que zero.");
    }
    this.preco = preo;
}
```

Note que no primeiro exemplo, simplesmente se corrigiu o valor errado, já no segundo atirou-se uma `RuntimeException` (supondo que estamos utilizando java).

Para getters, a lógica é a mesma, caso o valor da propriedade a ser recuperada não esteja adequada por qualquer motivo, ela deve ser ajustada ao ser retornada a classe cliente.

Answer (score 18):

A princípio pode parecer que não faz diferença entre deixar seu atributo público ou deixar privado com getters e setters sem validações, pois seu acesso está livre para modificações de ambos os jeitos.

Entretanto se um dia você perceber que deve validar o atributo antes de atribuir seu valor você perceberá a diferença de ter optado por um dos dois casos citados acima. Se você já tem o getter e o setter você poderá fazer a validação dentro da sua classe sem alterar as classes que dependem delas, mas se você tinha definido seu atributo como público e você mudar para privado você vai quebrar todas as classes externas que acessavam o atributo livremente.

#### Princípio do aberto-fechado

De acordo com o princípio do Aberto-Fechado seu código deve estar aberto para extensão e fechado para modificações, e ao modificar seu atributo de público para privado você feriu o princípio, pois você pode fazer com que outras classes nem sequer compilem ao tentar acessar o atributo; Se você corrigir a sua classe validando o valor antes de atribuí-lo você não chegou a ferir o princípio, é isso mesmo, você fez sim uma modificação no seu código, mas baseado no Meyer's OCP isso é aceitável, pois você está corrigindo o que pode-se chamar de erros, e as classes que dependem dela ainda vão funcionar, é claro que o comportamento pode mudar já que o valor usado ao chamar o método set() pode ser diferente do atribuído dentro da implementação desse setter.

Veja dois exemplo de aplicaçoes do princípio aberto-fechado, um usado no Polimorphic OCP e outro o Meyer OCP: [Princípio aberto/fechado - como entender isso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15645/3117)

Comment: fique tranquilo esse dia nunca vai chegar => "Entretanto se um dia você perceber que deve validar o atributo antes de atribuir seu valor você perceberá a diferença de ter optado por um dos dois casos citados acima. " E se chegar, faça algo muito, mas muito simples => "Crie uma outra Entidade para o novo propósito!"