# Encapsulamento e Modificadores de Acesso Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento, getters

Uma pergunta bem simples:

Dado essa classe:

```
public class User {

  private String nome;

  //get/set

  public boolean fazQualquerCoisa(){
    **duvida**.equals("algumacoisa");
 }
}
```

Dentro do método **fazQualquerCoisa()** eu devo fazer acesso ao nome diretamente ou usando o método get?

`nome.equals ou getNome().equals`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depende muito do que o seu método `fazQualquerCoisa()` faz e de como funciona o *getter* da sua String, se dentro do *getter* ele apenas tem um `return nome;` então tanto faz, caso haja algum tratamento específico da sua String que deve ser feito antes de ser chamado dentro do método, então o acesso deve ser feito através do *getter*.

Como podemos ver nesse tópico: [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/3117), muitas vezes as pessoas fazem os *getters* e *setters* única e exclusivamente pois estão acostumados a fazer assim sendo que na verdade não estão encapsulando nada, se for esse o caso, se encaixa no primeiro caso que eu citei: tanto faz.

Comment: Muito obrigado por me esclarecer isso!