# Como dividir o endereçamento de uma classe em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, engenharia-de-software, getters-setters

Qual a melhor forma de se dividir esse `Aluno`?

```
<?php
    class Aluno{
        private $nome;
        private $sobrenome;
        private $email;
        private $telefone;
        private $cep;
        private $rua;
        private $endereco;
        private $numero;
        private $logradouro;
        private $cidade;
        private $estado;
        private $usuario;
        private $senha;

        public function getNome(){
            return $this->nome;
        }
        public function setNome($nome){
            $this->nome = $nome;
        }

        public function getSobrenome(){
            return $this->sobrenome;
        }
        public function setSobrenome($sobrenome){
            $this->sobrenome = $sobrenome;
        }

        public function getEmail(){
            return $this->email;
        }
        public function setEmail($email){
            $this->email = $email;
        }


        public function getTelefone(){
            return $this->telefone;
        }
        public function setTelefone($telefone){
            $this->telefone = $telefone;
        }

        public function getCep(){
            return $this->cep;
        }
        public function setCep($cep){
            $this->cep = $cep;
        }

        public function getRua(){
            return $this->rua;
        }
        public function setRua($rua){
            $this->rua = $rua;
        }

        public function getEndereco(){
            return $this->endereco;
        }

        public function setEndereco($endereco){
            $this->endereco = $endereco;
        }

        public function getNumero(){
            return $this->numero;
        }
        public function setNumero($numero){
            $this->numero = $numero;
        }

        public function getLogradouro(){
            return $this->logradouro;
        }
        public function setLogradouro($lougradouro){
            $this->lougradouro = $logradouro;
        }


        public function getCidade(){
            return $this->cidade;
        }
        public function setCidade($cidade){
            $this->cidade = $cidade;
        }


        public function getEstado(){
            return $this->estado;
        }
        public function setEstado($estado){
            $this->estado = $estado;
        }

        public function getUsuario(){
            return $this->usuario;
        }

        public function setUsuario($usuario){
            $this->usuario = $usuario;
        }

        public function getSenha(){
            return $this->senha;
        }

        public function setSenha($senha){
            $this->senha = $senha;
        }



    }
?>
```

Seria relevante separar algumas informações em outra classe como uma tabela de banco de dados? Tipo:

```
Class Telefone{
       private $ddd;
       private $numero;

      public function getDDD(){
        return $this->ddd;
      }
      public function setDDD($ddd){
        $this->ddd = $ddd;
      }
      public function getTelefone(){
        return $this->telefone;
      }
      public function setTelefone($telefone){
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
      }
```

Devo aplicar essas classes e métodos no  estado (`Class Estado` get e set estado), cidade (`Class Cidade` get e set cidade), endereço (`Class Endereço` contendo número, cep, complemento, lougradouro *getters* e *setters* etc).

Isso também se aplicaria com `Usuário` e senha criar uma classe apenas para os dois?

Exemplo:

```
Class Estado{
       private $estado;

          public function getEstado(){
            return $this->estado;
          }
          public function setEstado($estado){
            $this->estado = $estado;
          }
}

Class Cidade{
       private $cidade

       public function getCidade(){
         return $this->cidade;
       }
       public function setCidade($cidade){
         $this->cidade = $cidade;
}
```

Etc.

OBS: Na hora de eu modelar algo desse tipo, tem alguma técnica específica para separar corretamente ou vai depender do programador?

Comment: Primeiro, pergunte-se "por que estou usando classes?", depois, "por que estou deixando todos os atributos privados e fazendo 1 getter e 1 setter pra cada um?", e então "quais as vantagens e desvantagens de estar todos na mesma classe, e de estar divididos?"

Comment: Eu me perguntei, e surgiu a dúvida... Uma classe realmente contém todos esses atributos e métodos? Um exemplo, se eu colocasse tudo em Aluno ficaria enorme, estranho não? Atributos privados por questões de "segurança", por mais que seja apenas algo simples... Minhas vantagens e desvantagens seria a tal da minha pergunta referente a vocês rs.

Comment: por que é mais seguro deixar privado se tem dois métodos que dão total acesso a esse atributo? No seu exemplo de uma classe Telefone, seria útil se o Aluno pode ter mais de um telefone, assim a classe teria um array de objetos Telefone, mas por que criar um objeto que só vai ter dois atributos? Um simples array de string não seria suficiente? Uma dica é, tente fazer tudo da forma mais simples possível, só adicione complexidade quando essa complexidade realmente trouxer algum benefício relevante

Comment: Entendi, porém se eu deixar os métodos privados não vão conseguir se comunicar com outra Classe. Sobre a complexidade, seria tentar deixar mais difícil para construir e facilitar na hora de executar... A última pergunta, classes com OO funcionam como uma tabela de banco de dados certo? Por isso surgiu essa dúvida... Se por acaso eu tivesse fazendo tabelas em um banco seria isso  para manter a integridade dos dados. Porém não entendo até o fundo onde vai o limite que devo aplicar em uma classe... Enfim, obrigado pela resposta Guilherme.

Comment: _"classes com OO funcionam como uma tabela de banco de dados certo?"_ Não, tabelas não podem implementar ou extender outras tabelas, mas você pode criar uma classe que represente a estrutura de uma tabela, importante fresar que OO vai muito além de usar classes, nessas suas classes não vejo OO. Recomendo ler: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104340/ e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25995/

Comment: Depende dos requisitos do seu projeto. Um telefone pode existir sem usuário? Um usuário pode possuir mais de um telefone? Mais de um usuário podem possuir o mesmo telefone? O mesmo para o endereço. Você já levantou todos os requisitos que seu código precisa satisfazer?

Comment: Obrigado gente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já comentaram mas quero reforçar. Você está programando como se estivesse em Java. Em PHP geralmente não precisa de nada disso. PHP é uma linguagem de *script*, ela foi criada para fazer código simples e as pessoas começaram criar código complexos, e diga-se de passagem, desnecessários. Em geral elas não sabem porque eles estão fazendo aquilo, apenas fazem porque viram em algum lugar alguém fazendo, sem entender a realidade e contexto de quem fez. Provavelmente essa pessoa fez pelo mesmo motivo que você fez, portanto só porque viu outra pessoa fazendo. É uma brincadeira de Macaco Simão que nada tem a ver com engenharia, que é nossa área profissional.

Outro problema com a pergunta é querer saber a melhor forma de pessoas aleatórias na internet que não conhecem seu problema. Ou pior ainda, o seu problema pode ser artificial. As pessoas acham que "resolver" problemas artificiais ensinam desenvolver software, mas não ensina, no máximo ensina usar um mecanismo da linguagem, o que não é o caso da pergunta, ela quer saber sobre organização de estrutura de dados, que só é útil quando se sabe 100% dos requisitos e de forma correta. Nós não sabemos.

Além disso, despende de como cada um está acostumado fazer, eu apagaria tudo e começaria de uma forma totalmente diferente, e simples.

Só você sabe se seria relevante separar em partes. Pode justificar isso? Haverá ganho? Serve a algum propósito? Não tem uma forma melhor para fazer isso? Pelo que demonstrou não precisa, mas pode ser só que você demonstrou errado para nós, se o fez assim qualquer tentativa de ajuda estará errada.

Modelar uma estrutura de dados depende essencialmente dos requisitos atuais e possibilidade de requisitos futuros. Modelar é experiência. É pegar casos reais, detalhados e ver se funciona ou não ao longo do tempo e aprender com os erros, ou até usar a experiência de outras pessoas para mostrar onde estão os erros, desde que se tenha todas informações necessárias. Modelar tem a ver com pensamento lógico adequando. É entender coisas que sequer são de computação.

As respostas aos comentários mostra que está preso a uma visão de fazer as coisas. Por isso que eu odeio a maneira como as pessoas colocam coisas na internet, estragam a cabeça das pessoas pra sempre. A pessoa não consegue mais enxergar outra forma de fazer, tudo vira uma receita de bolo sem sentido.

Há controvérsias sobre o que as classes são, mas de forma geral elas são o oposto de tabelas de banco de dados, apesar de parecerem iguais. Eu até queria que fossem usadas de forma parecida, mas não é assim que as pessoas usam, mas o assunto é amplo demais para discutir aqui. De qualquer forma este caso parece que está está separando os dados individuais em tabelas separadas, isso parece muito errado, mas pode ser só porque não há requisitos claros na pergunta.

Comment: Eita. Obrigado pela resposta completa Maniero... Para que não ocorra mais dúvidas como essa você poderia me recomendar algo para estudar? Sou estudante de ensino técnico e não aprendi muito a fundo sobre tudo isso, e gostaria de saber mais e ampliar meu conhecimento, caso tenha alguns livros que possa me ajudar na minha jornada agradeço. Desculpe a inconveniência!

Comment: Pior que não, essas coisas não estão tão organizadas. Aqui tem muitas respostas que falam sobre essas coisas.

Comment: Entendi, valeu. Vou dar uma procurada.