# Getters e Setters são obrigatórios ou facilitadores?

Tags: java, sintaxe, getters-setters

Ultimamente tenho lido uns livros de Java, mas há uma parte que me faz confusão neste tipo de métodos acessores - gettters and setters.

A questão é:

Eu sou obrigado a escrever neste tipo de métodos, por exemplo, getName() ou apenas tenho que escrever getName() porque facilita a vida ao programador a atender melhor a programação orientada a objectos? A maneira de fazer os getters ou setters é uma norma ou uma convenção?

Se eu escrever, por exemplo, porName() ao invés de getName() o compilador não declara erro de sintaxe e cumpre a mesma função, apenas muda-se o nome do método.

Comment: Gets e Sets foram convencionados, assim como nome do método começar com letra minúscula e outras coisas mais.

Comment: Perguntas relacionadas: [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/43757/quando-usar-setters-e-getters) e também [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25995/getters-e-setters-s%C3%A3o-uma-ilus%C3%A3o-do-encapsulamento).

Comment: @LuizVieira Se esta pergunta realmente estiver falando de getters/setters em Java, a resposta correta seria a do Math. Agora se estamos falando de design de software, a resposta seria bem mais ampla rs

Comment: @wryel Verdade. Só achei relevante citar as outras perguntas porque esta pergunta também questiona se são 'facilitadores'.

Comment: Adicionalmente ao comentário de @emanuelsn, alguns frameworks (ou especs para frameworks) se utilizam desta convenção para fazer o seu trabalho (JSF utiliza e é uma opção no Hibernate). Na minha visão esta é a resposta: **é uma convenção para facilitar a comunicação, e é uma convenção funcional para alguns frameworks**. Já a resposta ao título da pergunta, que não tem nada a ver com o seu conteúdo, é: **usar *getters* e *setters* não é obrigatório**. Usamos *getter* para permitir que um atributo seja lido fora da classe e usamos *setter* para permitir que ele seja modificado fora da classe.

Answer (score 24):

> A maneira de fazer os getters ou setters é uma norma ou uma convenção?

É uma convenção determinada pela própria empresa que mantém a linguagem, a Oracle, como você pode ver em: [**JavaBeans Standard**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html)

O documento *JavaBeans spec* determina além dessa inúmeras outras convenções, todas elas com o objetivo de **facilitar a comunicação entre os desenvolvedores**. JavaBeans são classes Java que possuem propriedades. Propriedades são variáveis de instância com o modificador *private*.

Algumas das convenções que se referem às propriedades da classe são:

- Se a propriedade não é um *boolean*, o método acessor que pega a propriedade deve iniciar com *get*. Exemplo: `getName()`;
- Se a propriedade é um *boolean*, o método acessor que pega a propriedade pode iniciar tanto com *get* como com *is*. Exemplo: `isStarted()` ou `getStarted()`;
- O método acessor que atribui um valor à propriedade deve iniciar com *set*. Exemplo: `setName()`;
- Os métodos acessores (getters and setters) devem ser escrito no padrão *camelCase*;
- Para compor o nome de um método acessor a primeira palavra deve ser ou *get*, ou *set*, ou *is*, e o restante do nome do método deve ser exatamente igual ao nome do atributo;
- Métodos *setters* devem ser públicos com retorno *void*;
- Métodos *getters* devem ser públicos, não possuir parâmetros e ter o tipo de retorno que corresponda com o da propriedade.

Comment: Upvote. Uma coisa que eu tenho notado nos ultimos dias por aqui é um excesso de respostas com referências oficiais perdendo espaço para respostas de baixa qualidade sem qualquer referência oficial.

Comment: Ei Math! Sun, not Oracle (momento tiozao que ainda possui brindes de eventos da Sun em casa). :)

Comment: @wryel Apesar de que a única coisa não muito acertada na resposta é justamente a referência, uma vez que JavaBeans era um item específico de arquitetura Java EE, hoje em dia já bastante antiquado e caindo em desuso (a resposta em si, claro, está correta - as convenções valem para qualquer classe Java que queira usar getters e setters).

Answer (score 17):

Você pode escrever como quiser, pode ser

```
obj.colocaValorNoNome()
```

ou qualquer coisa, inclusive, se o seu atributo for público, você não precisa nem usar um método pra get e set, usando, por exemplo:

```
obj.nome = "";
```

Porém, pensando em padronização de código, boas práticas e segurança, a ideia é impedir que você mesmo ou outro programador faça alguma coisa errada com o objeto.

Desta forma, atributos que podem ser alterados e recuperados externamente, recomenda-se utilizar privado com getter e setter, pois você pode querer controlar esta manipulação, facilitando assim a manutenção do código.

E o padrão da nomenclatura é realmente para facilitar a manutenção por outros desenvolvedores, imaginamos que você quer reutilizar a classe em outro projeto, ou passar para alguém usar no seu projeto, o padrão é getAtt e setAtt.

Pra que complicar, se podemos facilitar?

Comment: Boa resposta. O que seria util complementar seria dizer que muitos frameworks utilizam getters e setters para acessar entidades relacionadas, como o JSF, com seus beans.

Answer (score 6):

Alguns frameworks dependem dos getters e setters para poder fazer melhor a reflexão em cima de sua classes. Como reflexão, entenda como metaprogramação, muito usada em injeção de dependências ou em frameworks de persistência (JPA, Hibernate e etc).

Em relação a nomenclatura, você deve sempre criar os getters e setter da forma como o @Math falou na resposta dele, porém nem sempre é necessário criar getters e setters para o seu os atributos do seu objeto. Você pode criar objetos imutáveis, e a partir de parâmetros nos construtores ou fábricas você já o cria com todos os seus atributos feitos, como por exemplo na classe Circulo abaixo:

```
package encurtador;

public class Circulo {
    private double raio;

    public Circulo(double raio) {
        this.raio = raio;
    }

    public double getRaio() {
        return raio;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return raio * raio * Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Fica muito mais simples trabalhar desta forma, criando métodos já relacionados a função do seu objeto. Caso precise de uma circulo com um outro diâmetro, é mais simples você criar outro objeto. Desta forma você pode criar um pool de objetos e a máquina virtual sabe lidar melhor com objetos menores que vivem menos tempo do que objetos grandes que mudam de estado constantemente.

Answer (score 3):

É utilizado apenas em linguagens orientadas a objetos seguindo ao princípio de [encapsulamento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)).

Recomendo a leitura de :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method

Algumas Respostas interessantes também podem ser vistas aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407877/what-is-the-point-of-getters-and-setters

Quanto a forma de implementação (o uso dos prefixos `get`/`is` ou `set` ) é um padrão universal para a identificação desta categoria de métodos (um exemplo muito prático é os das `Beans` utilizados em `JSF`).