# Por que usar get e set no Java?

Tags: java, android, desempenho, getters-setters

Aprendi na faculdade a um tempo atrás que deve sempre usar *getters* e *setters* para acesso de valores em um objeto e ouvi dizerem que é por questões de segurança.

Então eu acabei sempre usando e vendo outras pessoas usando, até que comecei a programar Android e notei que o Google diz para **NÃO** usar, por questões de perfomance (somente no caso do Android).

Então para que serve `get` e `set`? É somente por boas práticas? Não entendi porque de boas práticas neste caso. O que influencia eu usar ou não?

A questão de segurança é verdadeira? Me parece meio sem lógica dizer isto.

Exemplo:

```
pessoa.getNome(); //acessando uma variavel privada com get

pessoa.nome; //acessando uma variavel publica diretamente
```

Comment: podias postar algum link de onde diz essa informação "Google diz para NÃO usar, por questões de perfomace (somente no caso do Android)"? sff (ATENÇÃO é só por curiosidade)

Comment: Olha este link, aborda de forma geral o conceito de encapsulamento/segurança http://www.guj.com.br/java/104592-heranca#564414 resposta do @vinigody

Comment: Relacionados: 1) [Getters e Setters são obrigatórios ou facilitadores?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33723/3117); 2) [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/3117); 3) [Why getter and setter methods are evil](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html) (Artigo em inglês).

Comment: Se não fosse pelo `Google diz para NÃO usar, por questões de perfomance (somente no caso do Android)`, diria que é duplicada. Como o @jsantos1991 disse, poderia nos dizer de onde tirou essa informação?

Comment: Esta em um artigo sobre dicas de perfomance http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html Me parece que o proguard elimina estes métodos quando gerar o apk

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Segurança" nesse caso se refere somente a um programador acidentalmente acessar uma variável de um modo diferente daquele pretendido pelo autor da classe (não necessariamente um programador diferente). Vou dar um exemplo:

```
class Fração {
    int numerador;
    int denominador; // Não pode ser zero

    public int calcular() { return numerador / denominador; }
}
```

Se você puder acessar as variáveis diretamente, você precisa sempre se lembrar de que `denominador` não pode ser zero. Mas e se você esquecer? No hora, não vai acontecer nada... Mas tempos depois, quando outra parte do código chamar `calcular`, ele vai dar um erro de divisão por zero. Numa hora que você não está esperando, e vai ficar parecendo que foi a chamada ao cálculo que provocou a exceção (tornando mais difícil depurar).

Agora, digamos que você mude a visibilidade dessa variável pra `private` e crie um *getter* e um *setter*:

```
class Fração {
    int numerador;
    private int denominador; // Não pode ser zero

    public int getDenominador() {
        return denominador;
    }

    public void setDenominador(int denominador) {
        if ( denominador == 0 )
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("O denominador não pode ser zero!");
        this.denominador = denominador;
    }

    public int calcular() { return numerador / denominador; }
}
```

Nesse caso, você *continua* tendo de lembrar que não pode passar zero, mas e se você esquecer, o que muda? Muda que a exceção será lançada imediatamente ao tentar atribuir o valor, apontando a linha de código exata em que o erro ocorreu, de modo que fica muito mais fácil identificar e corrigir o erro.

Note que, no caso de `numerador`, não faz sentido criar *getter* e *setter*, você pode fazê-lo (por convenção) ou não.

Há outros benefícios de se ter uma camada de abstração a mais em torno de suas variáveis, por exemplo permitindo que você mude a representação interna da sua classe mantendo seu contrato constante. Esses benefícios são mais significativos quando se deseja ter uma API estável, ou quando se programa em uma equipe grande em que nem todos sabem exatamente o que o código do outro faz.

Em geral a perda de performance em se usar um método a mais é irrisória frente aos benefícios que essa técnica traz. Entretanto, se você está sempre criando *getters* e *setters* "porque aprendi que é assim que tem que ser", mas nunca ou raramente precisa validar um campo, ou refatorar a implementação, ou não tem ninguém além de você mesmo consumindo sua API, aí a coisa muda de figura: não só você gasta mais tempo escrevendo um monte de código inútil, como as pequenas perdas em performance ao longo de todo o projeto se acumulam, podendo dar uma diferença significativa (eu duvido, me parece micro-otimização, mas vai saber... talvez o Java do Android não seja tão otimizado pra tratar desse caso quanto a JVM oficial).

Creio que essa é a razão por trás dessa recomendação de não usar no Android. O código fica "menos seguro"? Fica. Mas é só uma questão de ser mais cuidadoso na hora de programar (e isso sim é sempre "boa prática"). Em relação ao produto final, isso por si só não causa nenhuma vulnerabilidade no código nem nada desse tipo.

Comment: Então há um grande engando enquanto a segurança, eu ouvi na faculdade que segurança é sobre ataque de hackers, e li em artigos que também é por isso, por isso eu disse que é sem lógica, porque não consegui achar uma lógica para implementar isto visando segurança contra ataque de hackers. Quanto a perfomance, pior que faz diferença, realizei os testes e quando há muitas chamadas de varios gets, a perfomace cai drasticamente, comparada com não usar! (no android)

Comment: Realmente ele faz grande sentido quando há algum tipo de validação. Eu aprendi que deve usar sempre, e ao começar a estudar Android vi que tinha coisa errada nesse sempre. Você disse que em uma equipe grande, seria bom usar, mas isto não seria pior? Levando em conta que a manutenção é maior e pode gerar erros quando usado gets e sets? (desconsiderando as validações... Usando apenas para retornar e setar valores simples)

Comment: @felipe.rce Eu não sou a melhor pessoa pra responder isso, pois sempre trabalhei em equipes pequenas, não tenho experiência prática desenvolvendo grandes sistemas. O que eu sei é que quanto maior a equipe maior a importância da robustez do código e de uma API estável, 1º para evitar do código de um causar erros no código do outro, 2º pra você ter liberdade pra alterar seu código sem quebrar o código de todo mundo na equipe. Se seu atributo era `Foo` mas você achou melhor usar `Bar`, você pode alterar a propriedade pra `Bar` mas manter os métodos como estão - fazendo a conversão nos (g/s)etter.

Comment: Esse é um exemplo **teórico** de como *getters* e *setters* ajudam a manter uma API estável, mas de novo, não tenho experiência suficiente pra corroborar ou refutar isso. Eu me lembro que nas próprias bibliotecas do Java havia alguns exemplos disso, vou procurar saber e se encontrar atualizo aqui.

Comment: Não é exatamente a mesma coisa, mas veja por exemplo a classe [`Date`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java): quando foi concebida, ela tinha vários atributos [conceituais] consultáveis e editáveis, como `minutes`, `hours`, `month`, etc. Não demorou muito (1.1!) pra notarem que isso estava ruim - dada a variedade de fusos horários ou mesmo calendários diferentes do Gregoriano. Os *getters* e *setters* não podiam ser removidos, então foram marcados como obsoletos (*deprecated*) e adaptados à nova implementação, mas mantidos até hoje.

Answer (score 10):

A utilização de métodos get e set, é praticada por questões de segurança. O método aplicado nesse caso é o encapsulamento. O objetivo de fato é não permitir que variáveis sejam modificadas diretamente. Por exemplo, vamos imaginar a possível estrutura de classe a seguir:

```
public class Ponto {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Ponto(){}

   // métodos da classe.
}
```

A partir do momento em que se instancia o objeto Ponto, você tem acesso direto as variáveis x e y. O mais comum de se fazer nesses casos é mudar a visibilidade da variável, geralmente se utiliza "private" ao invés de "public". Logo em seguida vem os adoráveis gets e sets.
Com a utilização dos gets e sets você passa a permitir que uma variável de visibilidade private possa ser acessada. Vamos a outro exemplo:

```
public class Ponto {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Ponto(){}

    public int setX(int valor){
       this.x = valor;
    }

    public int getX(){
       return this.x;
    }


   // métodos da classe.
}
```

No exemplo acima, somente através dos métodos getX e setX é possível manipular a variável X, enquanto que a variável Y por não possuir get e set não pode ser acessada diretamente.
Agora a parte mais importante. **Não faz sentido criar classes com variáveis de visibilidade private se você vai criar para todas elas (variáveis) o get e set**. Hora, se o objetivo da private é impossibilitar o acesso, que sentido faz usar get e set se os mesmos dão acesso direto a variável?
Mas porque de fato utilizamos? simples, por padronização, mas devemos utilizar de forma moderada. Pelos motivos já citados.

Abraço.

Comment: Então, eu não entendo motivos de segurança, sendo que acontece o que você citou em negrito... Se o Google diz que não é para usar no Android, então ele estaria menos seguro? Isso é estranho, ainda estou confuso... Outro problema seria se a classe tivesse muitas variaveis, gerando varias linhas de gets e sets e dando trabalho para manutenção

Comment: @felipe.rce leia a outra resposta. Apesar desta não estar tecnicamente errada ela está um pouco confusa e no fundo não explica o que você perguntou.

Comment: "Não faz sentido criar classes com variáveis de visibilidade private se você vai criar para todas elas o get e set." Como?

Answer (score 7):

Sendo curto e grosso... Se tudo o que o seu acessor `get` faz é retornar um campo da classe, e tudo que seu acessor `set` faz é alterar o valor desse campo, tipo assim:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private int _idade;

    public int getIdade() { return _idade; }
    public void setIdade(value) { _idade = value; }
}
```

...Talvez você devesse tornar seu campo público.

Isso não dá segurança alguma. Se houver consideração de performance, é porque sua pilha de execução fica um nível mais alta para manipular o valor da variável idade.

Outra consideração sobre segurança é que existe uma técnica de programação chamada **Reflexão**. Deixo a seu cargo pesquisar sobre isso, mas de forma resumida: tornar uma variável privada não significa que ela não pode ser lida ou alterada diretamente por outras classes. Você apenas tornou essas operações mais caras em termos de processamento.

Acessores são métodos e como tal servem para executar alguma lógica que seja de seu interesse. Por exemplo, supondo que você tem uma propriedade por referência, como uma lista. Vamos dar à nossa classe pessoa uma lista de filhos:

```
public class Pessoa {
    public List<Pessoa> filhos;
}
```

Se você tentar acessar essa propriedade em uma instância, pode receber erro de ponteiro nulo.

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
p.filhos.Add(new Pessoa()); // você acessou uma variável nula.
```

Agora vamos fazer um acessor realmente útil. Tenhamos a cortesia de garantir ao utilizador de nossa API que ele será capaz de acessar uma lista garantidamente instanciada, assim:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private List<Pessoa> _filhos;
    public List<Pessoa> getFilhos() {
        if (this._filhos == null) {
            this._filhos = new List<Pessoa>();
        }
        return this._filhos;
    }
}
```

Agora isso nunca vai dar erro de ponteiro nulo:

```
Pessoa p = new Pessoa();
p.getFilhos.Add(new Pessoa());
```

A ideia por trás dos acessores é essa: uma série de operações necessárias para se ler ou escrever valores para a classe fica encapsulada neles.

A segurança dos acessores, portanto, depende do que neles estiver implementado. Em casos como o exemplo que usei, a segurança está em se evitar uma exceção de ponteiro nulo. Outros aspectos com relação a segurança podem envolver verificação de permissões, impedir divisões por zero, garantir que acesso a arquivos não irá causar *lock* nesses arquivos etc.

Comment: +1 Concordo com tudo, mas gostaria de acrescentar que o acesso direto via reflexão é sujeito às políticas de segurança da JVM (via `SecurityManager`). Por exemplo, chamar [`obj.getClass().getDeclaredField(nomeDoAtributoPrivado)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29) pode lançar uma `SecurityException`. Ou seja, em certas circunstâncias o `private` *realmente* impede seu acesso por outras classes. Embora, que eu saiba, a maioria dos códigos Java não habilita essas restrições de segurança, exceto Applets (isso ainda existe? rsrs).