# Receber valor de variáveis de outras classes

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Uma classe que contenha as variáveis e seus valores, e preciso de alguma maneira simples de alimentar a outra classe com essas variáveis.

Por exemplo, eu tenho uma classe com a variável `String urlPage = 'www.abc.com'`. Essa `urlPage` pode mudar as vezes, mas eu não queria mudar em todas as classes que utilizam esse valor, queria mudar só na classe onde ela é definida. Assim, nas outras classes, em seus devidos métodos, eu só informaria a variável, e eles já entenderiam que seu valor é 'www.abc.com'.

Fiz isso funcionar com `get` e `set`, mas queria saber se existe uma maneira mais simples, pois não se trataria apenas de uma variável, seriam varias, e eu acho que daria um trabalho fazer um `get` e `set` pra cada uma.

Eu fiz o seguinte:

```
public class UsedLinks { 

private String homepagelink = "abc.com.br"; 

public void setHomepage( String homepage)
{ this.homepagelink= homepage; } 

public String getHomepage()

{ return this.homepagelink; } }
```

Já na outra classe, eu só chamei

```
Usedlinks link = new Usedlinks(); 
link.gethomepage();
```

Só que eu achei muito trabalho sendo que usarei não só o URL como variável.

Comment: Mostre o que fez. Mas a princípio é isto mesmo. A não ser que prefira fazer a variável ter acesso público. Não é recomendado, mas pode ser usado.

Comment: Coloca o código completo fica mais fácil de responde. Aproveite para se familiarizar com o site na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Poderia me explicar como fazer pra chamar a variável com acesso público? Não teria problema por enquanto. @bigown:

Comment: @LuísGustavoVieira você só precisa colocar o modificador de acesso `public` na hora de declarar a variável.

Comment: A IDE faz os gets e os sets para você, qual IDE voce usa?

Comment: Editei o post, pois não consegui comentar o código bem formatado @rray

Comment: Eclipse @DavidSchrammel

Comment: Bem vindo à Java. =]

Comment: Faz o eclipse gerar esses códigos, pelo teclado pode fazer, `ctrl+3` digite `ggas` marca as opções desejadas e ok.

Comment: Então clique com o botao direito do mouse  -> `Source` -> `Generate Getters and Setters...`

Comment: cara...como nunca me falaram isso antes? Bem mais facil. Obrigado!

Comment: @LuísGustavoVieira Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Para simplificar pode fazer o atributo ser público, assim não precisa criar o par de métodos de acesso:

```
public class UsedLinks {
    public String homepagelink = "abc.com.br";
}
```

Uso:

```
Usedlinks link = new Usedlinks(); 
link.homepagelink;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Variable.java).

Há [desvantagens em fazer isto e deve ser evitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40416/101), mas não está errado se souber o que está fazendo. Não é difícil fazer do jeito correto e alguns IDEs até automatizam o processo.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33723/101).

Comment: Entendi. Esse é o jeito mais facil mesmo. É pq eu tinha uma ideia na cabeça aonde seria possível:

Declarar a variável como você fez, e ao invés de instanciar do jeito que você fez, simplesmente colocar o nome da variável 'link' em outra classe e ela reconhecer como uma variável publica com valor 'abc.com.br'. Mas acho que sonhei alto né? hahah

Mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Comment: Ou você troca para C# e tem o melhor dos dois mundos :P

Comment: Não dê ouvidos á @bigown, venha para o php! :D

Answer (score 1):

eu criaria o objeto da classe em cada canto que vc precisar mudar, e criaria um metodo para alterar os valores daquelas que vc acha de precisam sofrer alteração