# Para que serve os métodos get e set em um array de String?

Tags: java

Eu não estou conseguindo preencê-los e mostrar o resultado na tela com a utilização desses métodos.
Para mostrar o que tem no array eu utilizei outro método o listarArray e para inserir dados no array utilizei o addArray.

Para que serve afinal o set e get no array, alguém me explica com códigos em java, por favor?

```
public class Aluno {

private String nome;
private String matricula;
private int idade;
private String[] cursos = new String[5];

public String[] getCursos() {
    return cursos;
}

public void setCursos(String[] cursos) {
    this.cursos = cursos;
}
...// outros getters e setters
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar os trechos de código dos quais você se refere, por favor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O atributo `cursos` é do tipo `String[]` e está declardo com o modificador `private`. Isso significa que ele é acessível apenas de dentro da classe `Aluno`.

Porém, pode ser necessário acessá-lo a partir de uma instância criada da respectiva classe. Por causa disso, é muito comum o uso de métodos para que isso seja possível. `Gets` e `Sets` é uma nomencaltura muito utilizada (principalmente em Java) para se referir a métodos que permitem obter e alterar o conteúdo de um atributo privado.

Portanto, o método `getCursos()` nada mais faz do que retornar o atributo `cursos`. Já o `setCursos()`, permite alterar o atributo `cursos`.

Exemplo do uso de `get` e `set`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno();

    //Utilizando o getCursos() para poder alterar o conteúdo do vetor
    aluno.getCursos()[0] = "Curso0";
    aluno.getCursos()[1] = "Curso1";
    aluno.getCursos()[2] = "Curso2";
    aluno.getCursos()[3] = "Curso3";
    aluno.getCursos()[4] = "Curso4";

    String[] novosCursos = new String[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < novosCursos.length; i++)
      novosCursos[i] = "Curso" + i;

    //Utilizando o set para alterar o atributo alunos, passando
    //a referencia de um novo vetor criado acima
    aluno.setCursos(novosCursos);
}
```

Note que não seria possível acessar o atributo `cursos` a partir da instância `aluno` criada acima, se não houvesse o método `getCursos()`.

> Ainda não consigo entender...por que vc usou get e não set?
>   aluno.getCursos()[0] = "Curso0"; ?

A dúvida acima foi feita num comentário e achei muito pertinente, pois realmente quando estamos aprendendo pode existir essa confusão.

O método `setCursos` não altera o conteúdo de uma determinada posição do vetor, como pode sugerir. Em outras palavras, o `set`, embora signifique alterar algo, nesse caso, **não** é o conteúdo de uma posição específica.

O que o `set` faz é alterar a referência do atributo `cursos` da classe Aluno (saber um pouco de ponteiro pode ajudar a entender isso mais facilmente).

Alterar a referência significa o seguinte:

Quando um novo `Aluno` é criado com `new Aluno()` um vetor de 5 posições do tipo `String` é alocado e a referência desse vetor na memória é armazenada pelo atributo `cursos`.

Quando utiliza-se o `setCursos()`, altera-se a referência armazenada pelo atributo `cursos`. Portanto, o atributo `cursos` que estava referenciando um vetor de 5 posições na memória, agora está referenciando um outro vetor, no caso do exemplo acima, um vetor de 10 posições.

Já o método `getCursos()` é utilizado para ter acesso ao vetor `cursos` (note que ele apenas retorna o vetor `cursos`). Ter acesso ao vetor significa poder manipulá-lo (alterar o conteúdo das posições), acessar os seus métodos (como o length).

Por causa disso, para alterar ou acessar um posição do vetor é feito `getCursos()[i]`. Note que se o atributo `cursos` fosse `public`, então poderia ser feito `aluno.cursos[i]`.

Pergunta relacionada: [Por que usar get e set no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40416/3084)

Comment: cantoni obrigada, mas ainda não consigo entender, vou ter que estudar muito...dammit...E porque utilizar get e set eu já sabia só nao entendia o funcionadmento dele no vetor. Entende?

Comment: Sim. Entendi a sua dúvida. Eu estou elaborando um resposta. Vou fazer o possível para você sair daqui com isso entendido.

Comment: @AlineGonzaga, fiz uma edição na resposta.

Comment: Entendi mais ou menos. O resto é comigo mesmo...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35243/discussion-between-cantoni-and-aline-gonzaga).