# Por que é uma má prática ter atributos int?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, atributos, getters-setters

Vi na resposta a essa pergunta [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17015/qual-o-uso-de-uma-variável-estática-ou-final-em-java/17136#17136](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17015/qual-o-uso-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1tica-ou-final-em-java/17136#17136), que:

> É uma má prática ter atributos int, a menos que sejam "constantes" ou você queira simular estruturas como da linguagem C.

Por que essa é uma má pratica?

Eu desejo indexar cada objeto da minha classe com um índice único. Pra isso eu pretendo usar um contador.

```
private static int contador = 0;

public final int indice;

public Objeto(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.indice = contador++;
}
```

Haveria uma alternativa "boa prática" a essa implementação que fiz?

Eu declarei o atributo `indice` como `public`, porém `final`. Haveria a necessidade de fazê-lo `private` e um método `getter`, tendo em vista que o fiz `final`?

Comment: Eu acho que o utluiz apenas digitou errado na resposta dele. Pelo contexto eu acho que ele queria escrever "*atributos públicos*" mas por qualquer motivo escrever "*atributos int*" e isso passou batido. Não há nada de errado com atributos int.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Boas práticas

Vou te dizer o que é mais importante sobre este assunto: inventaram uma praga na cabeça dos desenvolvedores chamada "boa prática".

O mundo do desenvolvimento ficará muito melhor quando as pessoas pararem de falar nisso. Essa é uma forma de dizer "faz aí do jeito que eu estou falando e não discuta". O mesmo vale pra "má prática" que é um "estou dizendo que é ruim e ponto". Assim não precisa explicar nada. Se fosse bom ou ruim mesmo a pessoa explicaria. Assim o desenvolvedor que está lendo aquilo pode decidir por conta própria se é bom ou ruim e quando deve ou não usar.

Quase tudo que existe pode ser bom ou ruim na maioria das situações, mas sem entender o porquê, serve pra nada. Tudo tem exceção, claro. Então falou em "boa/má prática", fuja da resposta. Ou a pessoa não sabe do que está falando ou é tendenciosa (claro que pode ser só preguiça/pressa em responder, mas como você vai saber?).

E o que está chamando de [atributo na verdade se chama campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

## `int` como "atributo"

Aquela resposta *linkada* especificamente está muito além do escopo da pergunta dela e aí cai no problema de não fazer compreender o que realmente importava.

É um completo absurdo dizer que um "atributo"/campo não deve ser `int`. Nesse caso específico eu diria que não existe uma situação sequer que impeça, crie dificuldade, e principalmente seja uma "má prática" :). Um campo pode ser `int` sempre que for necessário.

Claro que ele não deve ser `int` se não é necessário ser. Mas aí é o que eu sempre falo: o certo é fazer o certo, não é fazer o que é "boa prática". E o certo só dá para saber no caso concreto. Toda vez que você faz o certo em algum lugar e tentar transpor isso para outra situação, está fazendo errado. Cada situação é única. Algumas coincidentemente devem ter a mesma solução.

Eu acho que a resposta queria dizer que não é bom ter um campo público exposto e se confundiu na escrita, só isso.

Sem entrar em muitos detalhes porque esta não é a questão aqui, isso é algo que pode ser ruim em várias situações, especialmente em Java, e recomenda-se usar um método *getter/setter* para acesso a ele. De qualquer forma a frase é bem infeliz. Não vou discutir isso aqui (mas discordo do que costuma-se dizer como verdade absoluta), o assunto é outro, mas *linkei* perguntas abaixo que falam sobre o assunto, se precisar de mais informações ainda pode fazer uma nova pergunta específica.

## Seu exemplo

O seu caso específico está usando o `contador` como privado. Ok. O problema do que está fazendo é que cria uma [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) em ambientes concorrentes. Você pode ter o contador aumentando em 2 ou mais antes de ser usado em cada um, aí terá dois objetos com o mesmo índice. É bem raro acontecer, e justamente por isso o dia que acontecer será bem difícil reproduzir e descobrir o porquê.

O que está fazendo não é lá uma ideia das melhores. Eu tentaria fazer de outra forma, mas como eu não sei qual é o problema, os requisitos, qualquer coisa que eu fale soará como "boa prática".

###Getter/Setter

O `indice` é público. Não há problema algum ser `final` e `public`. Isto em si não cria nenhum problema. Costuma ser melhor que seu acesso seja feito por um método *acessador* (veja nas perguntas abaixo o porquê), mas só costuma, se não tiver nenhum motivo para isso, pode deixar como público.

Eu concordo que em Java, que é uma linguagem que não gosta muito de *syntatic sugar*, costuma ser uma boa ideia acessar os campos por um método para garantir a melhor manutenibilidade. Se você precisar mudar a forma de acesso no futuro não precisará mudar todos os códigos que consumiram sua classe. Em outras linguagens isto pode ser mais conveniente e dar mais liberdade, se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo.

Em Java, pra expor um campo publicamente (qualquer tipo de campo) você deve ter certeza que nunca terá alterações na forma de acessá-lo. É raro ter tanta certeza assim. Mas tem casos.

O resto do que falam sobre o assunto é teoria boba.

A resposta do ramaral tem um exemplo de como fazer o acesso com um método auxiliar. Note que não tem um *setter*, afinal não faria sentido ter em um campo marcado como `final`.

## Conclusão

Nunca faça nada porque alguém disse pra você que é o certo, aprenda porque é o certo. Aí pode descobrir que a pessoa que te disse isto pode estar errada.

Fez certo em questionar aqui.

- [Propriedade Vs variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/133924/101) (é C#, explico ali porque não é o fim do mundo acessar o campo diretamente, se souber o que está fazendo)
- [É realmente necessário usar métodos para mutator e acessor (setter e getter) no PHP? E o desempenho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110785/101) (é PHP mas considero que o principal motivo para usar ou não está aqui, claro a resposta é minha :P)
- [Por que usar get e set no Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40416/101)
- [Getters e setters são uma ilusão do encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/101)
- [Getters e Setters são obrigatórios ou facilitadores?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33723/101)

Pra falar a verdade acho que nenhuma das respostas nessas perguntas mostram bem essa questão por completo, mas lendo tudo já ajuda entender e formar uma opinião própria.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Felizmente já ultrapassei a fase da obsessão das "boas práticas", não só na programação como na vida(fruto da experiência e da idade). Porquê comer camarão com faca e garfo se é muito mais fácil comê-lo à mão? Não deixe as "boas práticas/maneiras" influenciá-lo na resposta.

Comment: @ramaral é claro que se o camarão for sem casca, fica fácil e pode ser até desejável comer com garfo e faca, principalmente se levar em consideração onde está comendo. Sempre há uma exceção pra tudo :) Mas a metáfora é boa, tem gente que é chique fazer isto, mas quem é chique de verdade sabe que a mão pode ser a melhor ferramenta muitas vezes :) Não sei se entendi a última frase.

Comment: "resposta" não se refere à sua mas sim à pergunta de como comer o camarão. Ela(a frase) pretende dizer que não deve ser só a existência da "boa prática" a guiá-lo, deverá ter também em conta o contexto.

Comment: "É um completo absurdo dizer que um atributo não deve ser int". Concordo plenamente!

Comment: @ramaral, experiência e idade é o que muitos devs ainda não tem. Todos chegaremos lá um dia e não precisaremos mais de conhecimento empírico alheio. Mas, como diz o bigown, ***"pra falar a verdade acho que nenhuma das respostas nestas perguntas mostram bem essas questão por completo"***. Há situações difíceis de esclarecer mesmo gastando muita saliva. "Em vez de falar em boa prática, explique o porquê", mas esta explicação muitas vezes vai ser raza e não vai se afastar muito do "boa prática". Há respostas "lógicas" erradas, e há "boas práticas" erradas. Normal. O termo escolhido não muda nada.

Comment: @Caffé Nada tenho contra às "boas práticas", apenas acho que não devem ser usadas porque  existem. A sua utilização está condicionada a um contexto. Há ocasiões em que como camarão com faca e garfo, faço-o, porque o contexto o recomenda. O problema da utilização das "boas práticas" está, na maioria das vezes, na compreensão em onde/quando devem ser utilizadas. Neste momento deixo que seja o evoluir do desenvolvimento a ditar a necessidade, ou não, da sua utilização, a não ser que logo à partida seja óbvio o seu beneficio.

Answer (score 10):

Em relação a *"É uma má prática ter atributos `int`(públicos),...."* não vejo o porquê, quanto muito poder-se-á questionar se ter campos públicos, em geral, é bom.

O caso que apresenta nada tem a ver com "boa prática" mas sim com "bom senso"/funcionalidade.

Nesse exemplo, sendo `final`, não vejo problema em ser `public`, ele não pode ser modificado.
No entanto, pelo facto de em Java o uso de getter/setter estar de tal forma enraizado, pode/deve ser considerada a utilização de um *getter*, se necessita aceder externamente a ele.

```
public class UmObjeto{

    private static int contador = 0;
    private final int indice;

    public UmObjeto(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
        this.indice = contador++;
    }

    public int getIndice(){
        return indice;
    }
}
```

Também faria sentido se ele fosse uma "constante da classe", nesse caso teria de ser também `static`, o que não é possível neste caso.

Comment: Faz sentido *public final* quando o atributo precisa ser lido fora da classe mas só deve ser setado pelo construtor. E por que declarar o *getter*? Seria uma boa prática? :D

Comment: @Caffé "Seria uma boa prática?" Em Java, que não tem *Properties*, em termos genéricos é. Há necessidade de a aplicar sempre? Não. Neste caso em particular, concordo consigo, talvez não haja essa necessidade, no entanto, pelo facto de em Java o uso de getter/setter estar de tal forma enraizado, deve ser considerada a sua utilização.

Comment: Concordo, ramaral. E cá estamos nós nas boas e velhas boas práticas, sempre facilitando a vida de quem está compartilhando experiência e também a vida de quem está começando, ansioso para produzir logo, com boa vontade para fazer um código bacana desde cedo, mesmo antes de compreender ainda 100% de tudo que está fazendo. **Três vivas às boas práticas!** :D

Comment: Boas práticas podem tanto servir como um guia enquanto não "pega" experiência, quanto podem ser ignoradas. Pesquisar a fundo a razão por trás das boas práticas é preciso.

Answer (score 5):

## Concorrência

Se esta classe pode ser instanciada por mais de uma thread, declare o contador como [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) para garantir a sua integridade. Exemplo:

```
private static AtomicInteger contador = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

E, para incrementar:

```
this.indice = contador.incrementAndGet();
```

## Quanto a usar atributo *int* ou *Integer*

Use o ***int*** quando quiser o valor default **Zero** e o ***Integer*** quando quiser a capacidade de ter um atributo **null**.

No seu caso, se não houver execução concorrente do construtor (instância da classe por mais de uma thread), **int** serve muito bem.

## Quanto a declarar um *getter* para o índice

Depende da **natureza do seu objeto**.

Se ele é uma **simples estrutura de dados**, sem muitos outros atributos, se ele carrega pouco estado, pouco ou nenhum comportamento e as mudanças de estado são simples ou inexistentes, declarar como publico em vez de usar *getter* serve.

Agora, se este objeto é uma **entidade importante no sistema**, com complexos comportamentos e mudanças de estado, eventualmente vários atributos públicos, daí um *getter* pode cair melhor porque a classe pode ter mais necessidade de encapsulamento, uso uniforme, consumo em várias partes do código, e sofrer muitas mudanças.

De qualquer modo este é apenas um guia pois há quem prefira **sempre** declarar *getters* e nunca expor os campos da classe publicamente - por uma questão de padronização. A padronização é útil porque se já está decidido como fazer, você não tem que gastar energia tomando a decisão a cada vez, e como o *getter* é o método mais seguro, por assim dizer, ele serve em todas as ocasiões.

Eu particularmente não conheço motivos contra esta padronização - só dá mais trabalho pra codificar.

Por fim, talvez valha a pena mencionar que **há ferramentas que exigem que você declare *getters* e *setters*** mesmo em simples estruturas de dados. Em **JSF**, por exemplo, você declara na classe *getNome()* e *setNome()* e no código facelets você escreve apenas *objeto.nome* tanto para leitura quanto para escrita.

Comment: Suponho, então, ser mais seguro usar `AtomicInteger`. Especialmente para criar índices que sejam _únicos_ para cada objeto numa classe.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueN.Vieira Se estes índices serão incrementados em código que deve suportar concorrência (ambiente *multithreading*, código *tread safe*), sim. Na prática: se este construtor da pergunta pode ser invocado por mais de uma thread, use AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 1):

Para fins de esclarecimento:

***int*** é um tipo primitivo. Variáveis do tipo int armazenam o valor binário para representar o inteiro desejado. int.parseInt("1") não faz sentido porque int não é um objeto, portanto não tem métodos. int no java são tipos primitivos e, não criamos objetos com tipos primitivos.

**Integer** é uma classe. Objetos do tipo Integer armazenam referencias para outros objetos. Isto é bom, economiza memória (não tem boa prática, é fato). Isto é um exemplo de transformar uma string em um objeto Integer por meio de um método estático Integer.parseInt("1").

Para ser mais específico, Integer é uma classe com um único atributo do tipo primitivo **int** usado quando você deseja ter o poder de atribuir NULL ao objeto, não necessariamente zero. Isso é usado em diversas situações e interessante para coleções e tipos genéricos.

Aqui estão classes do padrão Wrapper para representar tipos primitivos em objetos:

byte / Byte

short / Short

int / Integer

long / Long

boolean / Boolean

char / Character

float / Float

double / Double

Essas classes estendem de Object e tipos primitivos não porque não são objetos. Para usar Generics são necessários objetos, não tipos primitivos.

Desde o Java 5 temos autoboxing e a conversão de um primitivo em objeto wrapper é feita automaticamente, porém em algumas versões específicas da JVM ocorreu problemas de desempenho nessas conversões. Talvez seja isso que alguém quis dizer com "má prática".

Lembrando que tipos primitivos podem ser comparados com ==, enquanto objetos devem ser comparados obrigatoriamente com .equals().

Answer (score -1):

Isso já foi citado nas respostas anteriores, mas vou ressaltar. Na prática, a maior diferença é que um **Integer** por ser *null* (não tem valor atribuído) e um **int** é inicializado com *zero* (não dá para saber se o valor é zero mesmo ou se simplesmente não foi atribuído nenhum valor). E, conceitualmente, se sua aplicação é orientada a objetos, seria melhor você ter objetos ao invés de variáveis primitivas.

Declarar um objeto **Integer** ao invés de uma variável **int** te disponibiliza mais recursos, mas se você não utilizar nenhum deles, não fará diferença na prática. Define-se como *boa prática* porque pode ser que um dia você precise usar, e daí sua aplicação já estará preparada para isso. Eu tenho dúzias de aplicações nas quais nunca usei, mas vai que...