# Quando usar Setters e Getters?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento, getters-setters

Estou estudando OOP e na parte de encapsulamento fiquei com uma dúvida sobre quando usar *getters* e *setters*, além de poder validar o parâmetro passado, qual a utilidade de se usar?

Eu poderia simplesmente "pegar" o dado pelo `__construct`.

Exemplo:

```
public function __construct ($valor1 , $valor2) { 
    $this->valor1 = $valor1;
    $this->valor2 = $valor2;
}
```

e

```
function setValor($valor){
    $this-valor = $valor;
}
```

Answer (score 20):

A visibilidade de uma propriedade (**public**, **private** e **protected**) são parte do **Conceito de Ocultação da Informação**, que é importante para se conseguir uma maior consistência de dados.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo:

```
class Db_Table {

    public $dbAdapter;

    public function __constructor( Db_Adapter $dbAdapter ) {

        $this -> dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;
    }
}
```

Nada impede o imbecil do Cletus de pegar esse código de fazer algo como:

```
$this -> dbAdapter = 'Oi, eu sou o Goku!';
```

E mandar o código pro espaço por definir um bordão de final de anime naquilo que deveria ser um objeto que implemente uma interface para o banco de dados ou estende aquela superclasse.

Esse problema se resolve alterando a visibilidade da propriedade e criando-se um *setter*:

```
class Db_Table {

    private $dbAdapter;

    public function __constructor( Db_Adapter $dbAdapter ) {

        $this -> setAdapter( $adapter );
    }

    public function setAdapter( Db_Adapter $dbAdapter ) {

        $this -> dbAdapter = $dbAdapter;

        return $this;
    } 
}
```

E o código agora é à prova de idiotas pois a propriedade *DB_Table::$dbAdapter* invariavelmente será uma instância de *Db_Adapter*.

Além disso definir a visibilidade de uma propriedade com **private** sem um *setter* definido torna ela **somente leitura** no contexto do objeto.

Porém, é possível **sim** manipular o valor de propriedade de visibilidade *private* e *protected* através de [Reflexão](http://www.php.net/ReflectionProperty):

```
$obj = new Db_Table( new Db_Adapter );

try {

    $reflector = new ReflectionProperty( 'Db_Table', 'dbAdapter' );

    $reflector -> setAccessible( TRUE );

    $reflector -> setValue( $obj, 'Oi, eu sou Goku!' );

    var_dump( $reflector, $obj );

} catch( ReflectionException $e ) {

    echo $e -> getMessage();
}
```

Apesar de Reflexão não servir para isso. u.u'

**Encapsulamento** já é um animal totalmente diferente. Ele envolve o princípio de reuso de código (*DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself*) que não existe apenas na Orientação a Objetos.

Proceduralmente, o simples fato de criar uma função para guardar um pedaço repetitivo de código já é uma forma de encapsulamento.

A diferença é que com Orientação a Objetos temos herança, composição, polimorfismo e todas essas palavras estranhas que eleva o potencial do encapsulamento ao máximo do seu potencial.

Por fim, a **Validação** a que você se referiu, já coberta pelo exemplos, só é possível através de um *setter* pois você não pode ter polimorfismo ou mesmo condicionais numa propriedade pública. Elas aceitam o que passarem para elas.

Autor Original: Henrique Barcelos

Comment: Obrigado, consegui entender o conceito, mas como assim "você não pode ter polimorfismo ou mesmo condicionais numa propriedade pública", não entendi essa parte.

Comment: Propriedades públicas funcionam exatamente como uma tribuição. O lado esquerdo recebe o lado direito do jeito que ele foi definido. Através de um método você pode especificar que uma determinada propriedade só poderá ser um objeto que estenda uma determina classe ou implemente uma interface específica (polimorfismo) ou pode usar alguns condicionais dentro do método para que o parâmetros possa ser de vários tipos diferentes.

Comment: Se a minha resposta ou a de outro usuário solucionou o seu problema, lembre-se marcá-la como resolvida. Sua dúvida hoje pode ser a de outra pessoa amanhã. ;)

Comment: `Autor Original: Henrique Barcelos`. Não seria legal por o link ou uma forma de encontrar o texto original? Gostei dele :)

Comment: Pois é, mas parece que desde que ele foi pra Espanha o blog morreu. Ele tem um jeito bacana de explicar coisas complicadas. Acho até que ele tem conta aqui, mas sem movimentação.

Answer (score 10):

Você usa *setters* e *getters* para prover o gerenciamento dos atributos do seu objeto. Ou seja, você pode mudar as variáveis do objeto depois de criado.

Em contrapartida, ao encapsular os atributos e não criar *getter* e *setter* seu objeto se torna fixo. Ou seja, você não poderá mudar os dados uma vez que ele foi criado. Você deverá passar os dados iniciais no construtor e depois disso eles não mudam mais, pois já que os atributos são encapsulados (`private`) e não definiu nenhum *setter*, não terá como alterá-los. Normalmente, em linguagens como Java os atributos são declarados como `final` (no PHP não sei se podemos declarar variáveis como [final](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.final.php), apenas em métodos e classes, e que nesse caso, indicam outra coisa) para indicar que são fixos. Esses casos são muito usados para criar classes imutáveis, que não mudam de estado durante sua existência.

Outro motivo, como você mesmo comentou, é para encapsular os dados da classe. Um dos conceitos básicos da OO é justamente essa, **encapsulamento**. Então se você deixar sua propriedades públicas, não faz sentido usar *getter* e *setter*, pois não terá encapsulamento.

Um dos pontos mais importantes do *getter* e *setter*, é a **escalabilidade**. Imagine que você tenha um classe sem *getter* e *setter* e em várias linhas do seu projeto você faz uso do atributo diretamente, sem o *getter* ou *setter*. Ao precisar fazer uma manutenção você teria que mudar todas essas linhas, manualmente. Agora se tivesse o *getter* e *setter*, seria apenas necessário mudar a função *getter* ou *setter*, e a mudança ia refletir em todos os seus usos.

Pelo mesmo motivo, o uso de *getter* e *setter* é bom para **debug**. Toda vez que você precisar debugar esse atributo dentro do seu projeto, basta colocar um *breakpoint* na função *getter* ou *setter*, e não em cada linha em que a propriedade foi usada sem o uso de *getter* ou *setter*.

Answer (score 4):

Vai ter quem pense: "Eu sei o que faço, então posso deixar os atributos públicos e pronto!"

Getters e Setters vão muito além disso, vejamos algumas utilidades:

Para fazer validações:

```
public function setIdade($idade) 
{
    if ($idade < 0 || $idade > 200) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Idade invalida');
    }

    $this->idade = $idade;
}
```

Para prover uma interface fluente, retornando o $this

```
public function execute()
{
    # executa alguma coisa
    return $this;
}
```

Para organizar a apresentação das informações

```
public function getInformacoes()
{
    $informacoes = array('nome' => $this->nome,
        'idade' => $this->idade,
        'sexo' => $this->sexo,
        'identificacao' => $this->identificacao);

    return $informacoes;     
}
```

No construtor deve ser passado o que é necessário para aquele objeto existir, por exemplo, não faz sentido ter um aniversariante sem um nome e data de nascimento, então estes dados devem ser passados na construção do objeto, e não após.

Já os presentes recebidos, serão ou não adicionados posteriormente

```
class Aniversariante
{
    private $nome;
    private $dataNascimento;
    private $presentes;

    public function __construct($nome, $dataNascimento)
    {
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->dataNascimento = $dataNascimento;
    }
    public function addPresentes(Convidado $presente)
    {
        $this->presentes[] = $presente;
    }
}
```

Um erro que muitos cometem, é deixar todos os atributos como privado, e criar getters e setters para todos estes, mesmo sem necessidade. Neste caso, os atributos que estão privados, praticamente passam a ser "públicos", já que é possível ler e escrever em todos.

Getters e setters só devem ser criados se houver necessidade, caso contrário, os atributos estarão sendo expostos sem necessidade, vazando encapsulamento.