# Por que é recomendado encapsular em POO?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

Teria exemplos pequenos pra me mostrar? Pra eu entender o por quê?

Estou estudando PHP, mas pode ser em qualquer linguagem.

Comment: Eu já tinha passado esse *link* em resposta anterior minha se tivesse visto não precisaria fazer pergunta, mas eu entendi que a pergunta era diferente. Não acho que a resposta lá fale o mesmo que perguntado aqui, tanto que eu estava fazendo uma resposta.

Comment: votei para reabrir a pergunta.

Comment: Relacionada: [Quando usar Setters e Getters?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43757/91)

Comment: Outra: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204355/o-que-acontece-na-vida-real-em-um-ambiente-de-desenvolvedores-se-o-programador-n